# JQuery timepicker flows out of HTML text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox, jquery-ui-timepicker

I'm trying to implement a time picker, in a text box. But the times are flowing outside of the box.

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Inside my HTML file:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.timepicker.js"></script>

  <script>

     $(function() { $('#time_picker').timepicker({ 'step': 15 }); });

 </script>
```

...

```
<label> Departure Time: </label> 
<input type="text" id="time_picker" name="depart_time"> <br>
```

[image]

Comment: you need to include one more css jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css

Comment: Thanks, I needed to add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.timepicker.css" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work fine

```
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="jquery.timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#time_picker').timepicker();
    });
</script>
```